# Show a div after submitting a form and showing new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

We've got a page where we can edit some things. When "submitting" the changes on the page, the page loads ind a new page.
So the action of the form, is a new page. Hope it makes sense.

I want to show a text when clicking "save" and the new page has loaded.

Tried this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    if 
    $('#saveform').submit(function()) && .load(function()){
             $('#output').show();   
    };
    else
    $('#output').hide();
});
```

Hi

And gave the form id="saveform".

```
<form action="/portal?page=profile" method="post" id="saveform">
```

But now the output just shows when the page is loaded.

So yeah. An edit-page with one template included - and a page with a different page included.

SO! Is there a way to show a div when form is submit'ed and a new page is loaded?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your JS feels totally broken... Does it even run? About your div, why don't you display it server side before returning it to the browser? Are you sure you want to do that client-side with JS?

Comment: When submitting your form a reload is performed and all temporary data is lost. So the only way to preserve an information is to save it to a cookie or session. On page refresh you can read the cookie or session based data and trigger your script, which shows your text info or modal box or whatever you like ...

Comment: you can use the backend to check if the `GET` variable `page` exists. Depending on what backend you use, you can fetch that value and see if it's set or not and load in your script around that logic. In PHP you would do the following: `if( isset($_POST['page']) ){ //script here }`. There's a few ways to do what you want basically. Without further clearification, it's going to be hard to give you anything else.

Comment: Thank you! I guess it must be a cookie session of some sort. My knowledge of javascript isn't that big,  so I guess I had put my expectations high :D